# ¿Cómo consultar todos los contenedores en docker con la docker API?

Tags: docker

Soy nuevo en Docker y estoy tratando de consultar todos los IDs de los contenedores por medio del API de Docker, pero hasta donde he podido ver solo se recupera la información de los contenedores que se encuentran en ejecucion (esto con el end point: "/containers/json").

Con el comando `docker ps -a | awk '{print $1}'` puedo obtener esos IDs que necesito, pero en producción no voy a tener acceso a ejecutar estos comandos, por lo que necesito hacerlo con la API de docker.

He revisado la [documentacion](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#tag/Container) sin éxito.

---

Con un parametro adicional se pueden consultar todos los contenedores activos e inactivos: all=1
La ruta completa para la consulta sería: http://localhost:2375/containers/json?all=1

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje de programación vas a usar?

Comment: Utilizare nodejs para consumir la api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer eso a través del API de docker tienes que instalar alguno de los [SDKs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/). Por ejemplo, con Python se puede hacer algo como:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> client.containers.list() # Por defecto, solo los activos
[<Container: 7ba807b075>, <Container: 145748efd2>]
>>> client.containers.list(all=True) # Todos los contenedores
[<Container: 27cbd12310>, <Container: f254a08a7b>, <Container: 934ae6b4e8>, <Container: 064b965aaf>, <Container: 32e57b34bf>, <Container: 5d2be91b77>, <Container: 327e9d6e7d>, <Container: b3a53e6bba>, <Container: 7123038fe7>, <Container: cf4b3bebf7>, <Container: a3572506b3>, <Container: 89d439a160>, <Container: fb36b65fce>, <Container: 65f77cb5fc>, <Container: 8754fc2747>, <Container: 7c4b74612a>, <Container: 6706337a47>, <Container: 7ca5af6f25>, <Container: 2edd6e42a2>, <Container: 7ba807b075>, <Container: 145748efd2>]
>>> contenedores = client.containers.list(all=True)
>>> for contenedor in contenedores:
...   print contenedor.id
... 
27cbd123103de3d35be4cff2f454865eb3bda269f5aec1591ba38c18cfe1519a
f254a08a7bae0deebaa96bec57f7394d41189c389237045d606cc113f776d2c9
934ae6b4e84c001de1486d787beeb8deeac91becb460d0dc429f60f1085a2a3d
064b965aaf6dbe18340b87213dc6a4c0661a0fd715957b02776062ce86d1e506
32e57b34bfd536b594646af0c4b4b0db02afbe080df91f42d0fcb32852db8727
>>> for contenedor in contenedores:
...   print contenedor.short_id
... 
27cbd12310
f254a08a7b
934ae6b4e8
064b965aaf
32e57b34bf
```

Por cierto, no es necesario usar `awk` para formatear la salida, puedes usar el flag `--format` para eso:

```
$ docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}"
32baa4cdb552
11e95c440340
c2f0776b9b73
198651352ca6
1a237d29bcd3
773abd6cef6c
1f7e227a2cf7
f9ae6aceeb87
f4de33b4895d
```

Lo que hace `--format` es usar un [go-template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) para formatear la salida. Puedes formatear la salida para usar las otras columnas: `CONTAINER ID`, `IMAGE`, `COMMAND`, `CREATED`, `STATUS` o `PORTS`.

Algunos ejemplos:

- Mostrar el comando ejecutado y el estado:

  ```
  $ docker ps -a --format "{{.Command}}\t{{.Status}}"
  "/sbin/my_init" Up 2 hours
  "docker-entrypoint.s…"  Up 2 hours
  "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"  Up 2 hours (healthy)
  "rsyslogd -n"   Up 2 hours
  ```
- Mostrar la imagen usada por el contenedor:

  ```
  $ docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}}"
  hopsoft/graphite-statsd
  redis:2.8
  voxxit/rsyslog
  ```
- Mostrar en formato tabla el ID y su imagen (se muestran las cabeceras):

  ```
  $ docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}"
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE
  e1cdde3a3c4c        hopsoft/graphite-statsd
  73888c7cb0bf        redis:2.8
  910b88a2d985        voxxit/rsyslog
  ```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta. El api lo voy a consumir desde nodejs. En teoria seria lo mismo que hiciste en python, pero como lo podria hacer desde node. Otro dato que olvide es que la consulta no la voy a realizar localmente, por eso el uso del api, la consulta de esa informacion la voy a realizar desde otro equipo.